# apply conceal to already defined syntax

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, conceal

I created my own syntax file tailored to UVM log files, in which each line is formatted in the same way:

```
<msg severity> <path>(<line number>) @ <simulation time>: <hierarchy> [<id>] <message>
```

example:
[image]

I defined the syntax without any "conceal", because by default the reader would want to see all the parts of all the messages.

However, I wonder if having broken up the line to different syntax constructs can be leveraged to allow some simple command to conceal and unconceal parts of the message.

For example if I have defined

```
syn region filepath start="\/" end="[^\(]\+" oneline
```

it would be awesome to be able to type something like

```
:conceal syn filepath
```

and have it be recognized because "filepath" is defined as a syntax.

Or better yet, conceal the type of syntax that's under the cursor.

Then later I would want to be able to undo it, in case I suddenly want to look at the file paths.

Cheers

Comment: I don't think you can conditionally hide individual syntax groups. Conceal is either on or off (with the exception of how concealcursor works).

Comment: Oh well. Once I realized that line wrap doesn't take conceal into consideration, the appeal of conceal went way down.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can conditionally hide individual syntax groups. Conceal is either on or off (`'conceallevel'`), with the exception of how `'concealcursor'` works.